# Querying open search with python, unable to solve serialization error

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, opensearch

I'm new to python and trying query opensearch with python, I'm able to get 200 response while connection to opensearch but when querying I'm getting serialization error, Thanks in advance

```
def create_open_search_session(host, port):
auth = ('admin', 'admin')
opensearch = OpenSearch(
    hosts=[{'host': host, 'port': port}],
    httP_compress = True,
    http_auth=auth,
    ssl_assert_hostname=False,
    ssl_show_warn=False,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
return opensearch

def get_severity(host, port):
try:
    sql_query= 'select severityId from services'
    # query = {"query":{"match":{"account_id":"554"}}}
    os = create_open_search_session(host, port)
    data = wr.opensearch.search_by_sql(client=os, sql_query=sql_query)
    output = json.loads(data)
    return output
except SSLError as e:
    print("SSL error : ", e)
```

This is the error I'm getting:
SerializationError: Unknown mimetype, unable to deserialize: text/html

Answer (score 0):

```py
output = json.loads(data)
```

You are trying to deserialize a json. But the mimetype from the respond is text/html. Debug your code and see what is in data. I assume it's a string.

Comment: still the same, I'm not able to get any response in the first place, my query it self is not happening.

Comment: Show us `search_by_sql`.